# Setting SLD rule title using field?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Can I set the title of an SLD rule using a feature's field?

I have a very dynamic dataset where the value of a polygon changes after each update, therefore I need to be able to compare using one field and label the style rule with another field to create a legible legend.

Below I have a rule using the SLD syntax. I am able to use a PropertyName tag to compare two values, is it possible to similarly use a PropertyName tag (or equivalent) to change the Description's Title tag?

```
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>0</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>0</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>myFieldName</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#820000</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000001</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
```

In GeoServer simply adding a PropertyName tag returns the following:

> Element 'se:Title' is a simple type, so it must have no element
>   information item [children].

I've tried adding a function within the tag and get the same result. Adding a PropertyName tag within the Description tag returns:

> line 11: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting
>   with element 'ogc:PropertyName'. One of
>   '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Title,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/se":Abstract}' is expected.

Comment: What did you try? What happened when you did that?

Comment: I'm asking a general question about what is possible within the SLD syntax. Can you pull a field from a feature and use it as a title instead of setting a static title?

Comment: Please take the tour and get a feel for the sort of questions that we like around here.

Comment: Does my edited question better fit your community standard?

Comment: why not try this out for yourself?

Comment: I did, and I'll go ahead and add that additional information. I was trying to keep the syntax and question clean to make the post useful for others with the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a rule title cannot be feature dependent, it's a static element that cannot depend on features (a single rule normally matches many, and the rule title is also used to generate legends, in complete absence of features).